# Why can't I switch off the LED immediately using this sketch?

Tags: arduino-uno, led

I hope the LED can fade out a period of time. Also, I hope I can switch off the LED immediately when it is fading, but I only can fade out.

```
const int buttonPin = 2;
const int ledPin = 9;
const int fadingDelay = 20000; 
int buttonState = 0;
boolean fadingState = false;
void setup() {


// initialize the LED pin as an output:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  // initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}
void loop() {
  // read the state of the pushbutton value:
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  // check whether the button was pressed
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    buttonState = LOW;
    // check the current LED status (on/off)
    if (fadingState == false) {
      // turn on the LED
        for (int i = 255; i >= 0; i -= 5) {
          if (buttonState == HIGH && fadingState == true) { 
          analogWrite(ledPin, 0); //immediately off
          i=-1;
          }  
        analogWrite(ledPin, i);
             delay(fadingDelay);   

    }    
    fadingState = false;  // save the current LED state (on/off)
  }
}
}
```

Comment: see the BlinkWithouDelay example. now your sketch stops for 20 seconds.

Comment: Your code is a mess, and won't work properly. You need to clearly define *what* you want to do before we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see anywhere where you are assigning `fadingState as true`.I can't understand this part

```
if (fadingState == false) {
      // turn on the LED
        for (int i = 255; i >= 0; i -= 5) {
          if (buttonState == HIGH && fadingState == true) { 
          analogWrite(ledPin, 0); //immediately off
          i=-1;
          }  
    analogWrite(ledPin, i);
    delay(fadingDelay);   
    }
```

If you are entering in a `if` condition with statement `fadingState as false`. Then in `for loop` you are having a `if condition` in which `statement` is `fadingState == true`.If you are entering in as a False then why are you looking for True Condition.

Then if you manage to sort that add `break;` in that `if` condition so that when LED turns OFF you will exit that `for Loop`.

And Here you are setting the button state as low `buttonState = LOW` if first If condition, then in that nested `if` without reading the `buttonState` you still looking for it as `HIGH`.